# Using a dynamically created variable to access named object in an object

Tags: javascript

finalVariables() returns an object that contains data accessible by .dataName notation i.e. finalVariables().mainViewWindow0 returns the string stored for mainViewWindow0. I'm trying to access mainViewWindow0 using a dynamically created variable, but for obvious reasons this doesn't work so well with dot notation, but I don't know how to work around it. Help to be had for me?

Please ignore the poor coding practice of having a hard-coded number in there; I promise to get rid of it later

```js
activePane = dot.id.substring(6); //gets dot # and sets it as active pane 
 var tempForPaneNumber = "mainViewWindow" + activePane + "";
 document.getElementById("mainViewWindowContent").innerHTML = finalVariables().@@@this is where I want to use 
        the string from "tempForPaneNumber" to access @@@
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Was hoping it was something simple like that

Answer (score 1):

```
finalVariables[tempForPainNumber]()
```

Should do the trick if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can access properties of an object either through the dot notation or through the use of brackets to specify the identifier for the property so `myVar.foo` is equivalent to `myVar['foo']`.  Therefore, if I understand what you are asking correctly you want to use `finalVariables()[tempForPaneNumber]()`